# who writes a DDL - DBA or the developer using the table

Tags: db2, ddl, database-administration

who in general writes a DDL for a table/view creation? Is it the requesting developer (to use it) or is the DBA? anyways the DBA will be running the DDL.

Comment: Bob. He does it. What a ridiculous question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my personal opinion, part of the DBA responsibilites is to work with the development team to design and develop the database, as indicated in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_administrator).

Designing a table has two parts, first the physical design (column names, column types, constraints, relationships, etc.) that is mainly responsability of the development team. However, the table is stored in a tablespace with tons of characteristics, and the DBA should provide the mechanisms to adapt that table to the database structure.

Taking into account these elements, the DDL should be written in two phases, with many interactions of the actors, in order to write a DDL that is good for the application, and the database keeps its performance, security, availability, reliability, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the DDL contains many instructions for the table's design as well as table's functionality, such as the tablespace it will occupy, data partitioning, index location, etc. These are all part of the database design which the developer shouldn't know. A DBA should never give a developer direct access to the table, instead functions and views should be established from needs. But this is based on the Organization's requirements. The requirements of that of a bank will differ than that of a video store.